Strange jquery selector behaviour
I am experiencing some strange behavior regarding selectors in jQuery.
This is the code I had:
$("#content").fadeOut();
$("#content").innerHTML = "some text";
$("#content").fadeIn();

fadeOut and fadeIn work fine, but the innerHTML doesn't.
But when I do this:

$("#content").fadeOut();

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "some text";

$("#content").fadeIn();


all works fine!
Am I doing something wrong?
I hope you people can help me.
ps. This is not my actual code. I now have a built-in function as a callback for fadeOut, but the behavior remains the same.

.innerHTML is vanilla JS. .html() is jQuery

This happen when you mixup javascript and jQuery.

$(...) doesn't return an element, it returns a jQuery collection object (and could be selecting multiple elements). Setting innerHTML on it has no effect.
$("#content")[0].innerHTML = "some text";

sets the HTML of the first (and only, in this case) selected element, and
$("#content").html("some text");

would do so for all the selected elements (one in this case).
